# How to export city polygon from google maps api

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3, export, area

I want to output the points of this area in JSON format.

Example of area:

[image: Example of area]

Comment: That isn't available (currently) via the API.  [Related issue in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=109)